# Client & Server java programs. How to detect the end of a transmission

Tags: java, sockets, byte

I have a client program and a server program. I send 512-byte packets, and I want to send some files. How can the server know when the transmission is finished?

I want the server program to receive some files before it stops running, and I want to distinguish between them. What I want to do is print out the number of packet received:

Packet number 1 has been received

Packet number 2 has been received

.

.

Packet number N has been received

And once I receive this file, I want to set this counter variable to 0, which means that I have to detect when a file is completely sent (it means to receive less than 512 bytes). Is there any way to count the amount of bytes received from the client program?  Which is the best way to do it? I am using byte arrays.

Comment: You need to establish some sort of framing.

Comment: Are/must you use a UDP socket? And must the "packets" be 512 bytes in size? If TCP is used instead, lots of the dirty work is taken care of, as is the need of creating such tiny individual packets. (With UDP you'll also have to detect cases like out-of-order or dropped packets and issue any relevant re-requests.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to introduce a delimiter. This will become part of your protocol.

When you're sending the files, you send the data. When there are no more bytes to sends, the client will send an `END_OF_MESSAGE` value to the server, indicating that there is no more data to send, then in your code, you've got something like:

```
String END_OF_MESSAGE = "ENDOFMESSAGE";

if(input.equals(END_OF_MESSAGE)) {
    // You know the client has finished their transmission.
}
```

***NOTE***: I would make the value of `END_OF_MESSAGE` far more complex than that. This is simply for demonstration purposes.

**EDIT**

As JB Nizet suggested, another option is to send the length of the file before anything else. That way the server knows when the transmission is finished when the amount of transferred bytes are equal to, or greater than, the pre-set size.

Comment: This is far from being the best way to do it. What do you do if the file contains "ENDOFMESSAGE"? Why not simply send the length of the file first, and then the file?

Comment: That's an option, but if you note the text I put at the bottom where I explain that "ENDOFMESSAGE" was only for the purposes of the example, the contents of the file shouldn't be an issue. The user can also send the length of the file, which is something I will include in my edit.